# How can I handle the command line exception in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-except, index-error

```
import sys

num_1 = sys.argv[1]
num_2 = sys.argv[1]
print(num_1)
print(num_2)
```

How can I handle this exception?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no exception here. This code is valid, and should run correctly. Please edit your question to include the output of this code on your machine so we can see what's erroring.

Comment: While executing program i am writing python3 2 3. But it is printing 2  for 2 times. So i want to handle exception for that.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code in python3 and it throws an `IndexError: list index out of range`

here is the solution

```
import sys

try:
        num_1 = sys.argv[1]
        num_2 = sys.argv[2]
        print(num_1)
        print(num_2)

except IndexError:
       
        print("list index out of range")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass two numbers as arguments, then you need to fix the index for sys.argv

```
import sys

num_1 = sys.argv[1]
num_2 = sys.argv[2]
print(num_1)
print(num_2)
```

Now when you will run your script...

```
$ python test.py 2 3
2
3
```

Comment: There is no exception in your code to handle. So, you just need to fix the logic of your code to perform your task.

Comment: Can we handle exception for having same index for different values. I mean it will show exception if both arguments are same.

Comment: Not exactly. You are the coder here and the user who runs your script doesn't have direct control over the code, which means that you can only write such a program with correct logic. If there are two variables initializing with same argument, you can just remove or change it by yourself.